# preserve multiple GET parameters in Django URL

Tags: python, html, django, request, get

In my django project I have a page displaying a list of times. On this page there is 3 GET forms which are for:

- Parsing through pages
- Selecting graph data
- Sorting items

If a user is to select a field in all of these forms the URL should look something like this:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/watchlist/?page=1&graph_data=price&sort=quantity_desc`

But when a user submits one of these forms it only saves that GET parameter in the URL. eg:

*selects page = 2*

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/watchlist/?page=2`

*selects sort = quantity_asc*

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/watchlist/?sort=quantity_asc`

The page parameter is over written when both parameters should be present in the URL. How can i preserve multiple GET parameters in the URL?

*views.py*

```
def watchlist(request):

    #get requests
    graph_metric = request.GET.get("graph-data-options", "avg_price")
    page = int(request.GET.get("page", 1))
    sort_field = request.GET.get("sort-field", "avg_price-asc")

return render(request, "App/watchlist.html", context=context)
```

*html*

```
<!-- Page number -->
<form id="page-buttons-form" action="{% url 'watchlist' %}" method="GET">
    {% for page_button in num_pages %}
        <input name="page" type="submit" value="{{page_button}}">
    {% endfor %}
</form>

<!-- Sort items -->
<form id="sort-form" action="{% url 'watchlist' %}" method="GET">
    <label for="sort-field">Sort:</label>
    <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="sort-field">
        {% for sort in sort_options %}
            <option value="{{sort.value}}">{{sort.text}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>

<!-- Graph data -->
<form action="{% url 'watchlist' %}" method="GET">
    <label for="graph-data-options">Graph Data</label>
    <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="graph-data-options">
        {% for graph_option in graph_options %}
            <option value="{{graph_option.value}}">{{graph_option.text}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: How about adding hidden inputs to each form corresponding to the fields in the other forms, and setting their values onsubmit based on the current query string?

Comment: could you show me an example of what that might look like?

Answer (score 0):

This is a proof of concept to demonstrate how you can preserve GET parameters when submitting different forms. Each form runs a function `fillHiddenFields` before submitting, inserting existing URL parameters into the hidden fields.

*Note:* Apparently this does not work as a StackOverflow snippet, so you'll have to run this on your local machine.

```js
function fillHiddenFields(event){
    // extract query params from URL
    const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());
    // find hidden fields in form
    let form = event.target;
    const hiddentElmts = form.querySelectorAll('input[type=hidden]');
    // update hidden fields with URL query params
    for(let elmt of hiddentElmts){
        if(elmt.name in params){
            elmt.value = params[elmt.name];
        }
    }
    // console.log form data to check that hidden fields are updated
    let formdata = new FormData(form);
    console.log(Object.fromEntries(formdata));
}
```

```html
<body>
    <form id="form1" action="javascript:void(0)" method="GET" onsubmit="fillHiddenFields(event)">
        <input type="text" name="field1" value="Field 1">
        <input type="hidden" name="field2" value="">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <form id="form2" action="javascript:void(0)" method="GET" onsubmit="fillHiddenFields(event)">
        <input type="hidden" name="field1" value="">
        <input type="text" name="field2" value="Field 2">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```